# discord.utils.find and discord.utils.get keep returning None

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get the Member object for a user in my discord server. I'm currently trying to use discord.utils.find and discord.utils.get to do that. However, none of the methods are working.

Code:

```py
from discord.utils import get, find

print(find(lambda m: m.id == 422087909634736160 , guild.members))
print(get(guild.members, id = 422087909634736160))
```

Expected result:

```py
DSL#8005
DSL#8005
```

Current result:

```py
None
None
```

Comment: Do you have discord privilege intents on?

Comment: Also if you want to get the member from an ID it's easier if you simply use `guild.get_member`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i forgot to set up my intents on the discord bot. Thank you to TKperson for commenting the solution.

```py
clientintents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='b?', intents=clientintents)
```